# Entry form in home page

Tags: form

I have an entry form in home page which the home page already using the entry object.

And I am placing the entry form in home page when i call

> {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.title }}"{% endif -%}

and this will grab the home page title, and this is not the result i want.
I need when the form submit and error return with value.

By the way, any source to learn about entry form? I don't see much tutorial about entry form. Thanks.

Comment: What does the hyphen mean in the tag? This part: "{%-". As in, what's the difference between {% if %} and {%- if %}

Comment: @NathanDHuening Using hyphens in your Twig tags allows you to remove whitespace. Have a look here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control

Comment: @JamieWade Ah.. Thanks for the explaination. Me myself also forgot this. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin to submit the entry, then the variable that the invalid entry is called is actually configurable, using the [entryVariable](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries#configuration) config setting.

So just create a new file in craft/config/ called guestentries.php, with this:

```
<?php

return array(
    'entryVariable' => 'invalidEntry'
);
```

Then from your template you can just check to see if `invalidEntry` is defined.

Comment: Hi brandon, what if not using guest entry but normal form? How do i change the variable like the same as guest entry? Cause my single page using "entry" and form too using "entry" as well.

Comment: @HsTung Currently it’s not possible with the normal entries/saveEntry action.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've got your home page setup as a Single. Which is a great way to go, and that's what is **automatically setting the `entry` variable**.

Here's a great walkthrough on creating an "edit entry" form...

> http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form

Keep in mind, that example uses `entry` to represent the entry being edited. That won't work for you, however, since `entry` is being automatically set as your home page Single.

So when you're attempting to modify another entry, I'd recommend setting it to a *different* variable name. Obviously you can't have your home page and other entry both be represented by a variable named `entry`.

```
{% set entryToEdit = craft.entries.slug('my-entry-to-edit').first %}
```

Then `entryToEdit` would replace any instances of `entry` in the [documented example](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what if that is new entry form but not edit form?
I want to retain the value when there is error occur after form post. the form exactly like mention in doc
`http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form`
How should I replace the entry variable in the form with something else since you mention single had use my entry variable.

Comment: That's an interesting question... Typically, when you submit to `entries/saveEntry` (as this form is doing) it will reload the page with any error messages attached to the `entry` object. Those would be accessed via `entry.getErrors()`. But... what would it return in this case? Would there be a collision when the page is reloaded? I suspect there would be... You may want to email support@buildwithcraft.com to get more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I got this plugin from Brandon.
https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries

And it solve the problem I face.
Now I able allow guest to submit entry and it able to change the variable not to use entry but any variable you name in config.